# how do you request a url that has argument in python

Tags: python, curl

there is a url that has an argument at the end of the url ( -s). I need to call this url in python. Url returns an html table and I need to get the second column value from the html table.

this curl command works:

```
curl "http://example.com" -s
```

I need to be able to do this in requests.get

here is what I have:

```
import requests

searchUrl="http://example.com"+" -s"
resp = requests.get(searchUrl, verify=False)
print(resp.content)
```

It looks like requests.get does take the " -s" argument to the url. Any ideas?

html table output is something like this:

```
<table id ='tblData' style='width:60%' border='1'><tr><th>Host</th><th>Environment</th><th>Agent Version</th></tr><tr><td>serverabc</td><td>prod</td><td>1.201</td>+</tr></table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by URL with an argument? `https://example.com-s` isn't a valid URL.

Comment: @0stone0 request.get on http://example.com -s does not work for me curl command would be like this curl "http://example.com" -s

Comment: `-s` is an argument to curl, not the URL. You need to look at the curl docs to figure out what it toggles, and then search the requests docs for similar functionality

Comment: In the `curl` manpage the `-s` flag reads: *"-s, --silent
              Silent  or  quiet  mode. Don't show progress meter or error mes-
              sages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data  you  ask
              for, potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect
              it."* You don't need "silent mode" with `requests` so just ignore that. At a higher level, it's important to understand that `curl` and the python `requests` module are two TOTALLY different programs. You can't take flags from one and just slap them on the other.

Answer (score -3):

resp = requests.get(searchUrl, params="-s")

Comment: The `params` on `requests.get` is not the same as the CLI curl options. This does not make any sense. This way you're requesting `https://example.com/?-s`. Please see [@JNevill's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71325400/how-do-you-request-a-url-that-has-argument-in-python?noredirect=1#comment126074346_71325400)

Comment: @0stone0, this answered worked